How to map ObjectIds to their documents with a single LINQ query?
Context: I am creating an e-learning app in ASP.NET Core with MongoDB.
I have a Course collection:
public class CourseDTO : DTOBase
{
    [BsonId] public ObjectId Id { get; init; }
    public required string Name { get; init; }
    public required string Description { get; init; }
    public required string ImageUrl { get; init; }
    public required ObjectId Teacher { get; init; }
    public ObjectId[] StudentIds { get; init; } = [];
}

And a User collection
public class UserDTO : DTOBase
{
    [BsonId] public ObjectId Id { get; init; }
    public required string Username { get; init; }
    public required string PasswordHash { get; init; }
    public required string PasswordSalt { get; init; }
}

I want to implement a method to fetch a course from its ObjectId and map the StudentIds to the related users.
If possible I would prefer to do it in a single request, and keep the query type safe.
So far I managed to fetch the Course with the "easy" fields, I am just missing the Students:
public async Task<CourseModel> Get(ObjectId id) 
{
    var query = from c in repo.Courses.AsQueryable()
                where c.Id == id
                join t in repo.Users.AsQueryable() on c.Teacher equals t.Id
                select new CourseModel 
                       {
                           Id = c.Id.ToString(),
                           Name = c.Name,
                           Description = c.Description,
                           ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
                           Teacher = new UserModel 
                                     {
                                         Id = t.Id.ToString(),
                                         Username = t.Username
                                     }
                           // todo: add students
                       };

    var course = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (course == null) 
        throw new NotFoundException("Course not found");

    return course;
}

public class UserModel
{
    public required string Id { get; init; }
    public required string Username { get; init; }
}

public class CourseModel
{
    public required string Id { get; init; }
    public required string Name { get; init; }
    public required string Description { get; init; }
    public required string ImageUrl { get; init; }
    public required UserModel Teacher { get; init; }
    public UserModel[] Students { get; init; } = [];
}

I could get the students in another query easily but it would be more efficient to do everything in one query.

Acording to your shared code snippet, you could utilize the lookup aggregation stage. This allows you to join the Users collection with both the StudentIds array and the Teacher field in the Courses collection, transforming the results into the desired shape with the Project stage.

@MdFaridUddinKiron thank you for your answer. I posted a working snippet as an answer to this thread. Do you see any way to improve my code using your method?

As suggested by @md-farid-uddin-kiron I used the lookup aggregation stage followed by project and got the result I wanted:
public async Task<CourseModel> Get(ObjectId id) {
    var agg = repo.Courses
        .Aggregate()
        .Match(course => course.Id == id)
        .Lookup<CourseDTO, UserDTO, CourseLookedUp>(repo.Users, c => c.TeacherId, u => u.Id, r => r.Teacher)
        .Unwind<CourseLookedUp, CourseLookedUp>(c => c.Teacher)
        .Lookup<CourseLookedUp, UserDTO, CourseLookedUp>(repo.Users, c => c.StudentIds, u => u.Id,
            r => r.Students)
        .Project<CourseLookedUp, CourseModel>(c => new CourseModel {
            Id = c.Id.ToString(),
            Description = c.Description,
            ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
            Name = c.Name,
            Teacher = new UserModel {
                Id = c.Teacher.Id.ToString(),
                Username = c.Teacher.Username
            },
            Students =
                c.Students.Select(s => new UserModel {
                    Id = s.Id.ToString(),
                    Username = s.Username
                })
        });

    var course = await agg.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (course == null) throw new NotFoundException("Course not found");

    return course;
}

